# Is it okay to use itinerary operators in python without assignment?

Tags: python, pep8

So, consider the case that I have to add values to an array based upon conditions.
I realized using ternary operators without assignment works as well.
Consider the case:

```
req_array = []
req_dict={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

I have to add values to `req_array` based upon condition. There can be 2 ways:

```
if req_dict.get("a"):
    req_array.append(req_dict['a'])
if req_dict.get("d"):
    req_array.append(req_dict['d'])
if req_dict.get("c"):
    req_array.append(req_dict['c'])
```

The other way of doing this is:

```
req_array.append(req_dict['a']) if req_dict.get('a') else None
req_array.append(req_dict['d']) if req_dict.get('d') else None
req_array.append(req_dict['c']) if req_dict.get('c') else None
```

Both of them works correctly. But, I was curious as to what is the recommended approach in these cases?

Comment: `req_array.append(req_dict['a']) if req_dict.get('a') else None` is bad. Don't use a *conditional expression* for side-effects. use an `if-else` **statement**, the whole point of a conditional expression is that it *is an expression, i.e. it evaluates to a value*, but you don't care about that value. So just use the statement

Comment: IMO more readable, more understandable and more maintainable way is prefered. From *my* point of view it is the first approach

Comment: Why not `req_array=[req_dict.get(key) for key in ('a','d','c')]`

Comment: Note also, `if req_dict.get("a"):` would be better written as `if "a" in req_dict:` although these two are subtly different, your original version will not go into the if block if `.get` returns *any falsey value*.

Comment: @dawg: That won't filter to things with truthy values (it just includes the falsy values and `None`s from non-existent keys too). `[req_dict[key] for key in ('a','d','c') if req_dict.get(key)]` works, or with 3.8 walrus operator to avoid double-lookup `[val for key in ('a','d','c') if val := req_dict.get(key)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd view using the conditional operator for side-effects with roughly the same disgust as using list comprehensions for side-effects. These are expressions intended to produce something, and you're using them to do other things while ignoring the thing produced (always `None` in this case).

If you really need to one-line it, you can always do

```
if req_dict.get('a'): req_array.append(req_dict['a'])
```

which, while still not great style (two lines are more readable), is perfectly legal, less verbose (add `:`, remove  `else None`), and doesn't imply the production of an unused value even when the `if` fails. With 3.8, the walrus operator even saves you from performing lookup twice, while still allowing you to one-line it:

```
if val := req_dict.get('a'): req_array.append(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, both options work, so it's a matter of personal style, mostly.

Personally, I find such ternary expression harder to read - they start with stating something will be appended to a list, but as you read on you find out it may not due to some condition. I would definitely got with the explicit `if` approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this depending on what exactly you are looking for.
Is condition always the same? Then you could define a list of keys and iterate over it.

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
req_array = []
req_dict={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
for key in keys:
    val = req_dict.get(key)
    if val:  # your condition here
        req_array.append(val)
```

Or one liner:

```
req_array += [req_dict[key] for key in keys if req_dict.get(key)]
```

There are many appropriate ways. Some are just a matter of preference.

If conditions are different for all of the keys, then i would go for explicit `if` as this is kind of more readable and the patter is vissually immediately recognizable.